# FOR loop should yield multiple results, but only yields one

Tags: python, list, dictionary, rss, iteration

I'm trying to pull very specific elements from a dictionary of RSS data that was fetched using the `feedparser` library, then place that data into a *new* dictionary so it can be called on later using `Flask`. The reason I'm doing this is because the original dictionary contains tons of metadata I don't need.

I have broken down the process into simple steps but keep getting hung up on creating the new dictionary! As it is below, it *does* create a dictionary object, but it's not comprehensive-- it only contains a *single article's* title, URL and description-- the rest is absent.

I've tried switching to other RSS feeds and had the same result, so it would appear the problem is either the way I'm trying to do it, or there's something wrong with the structure of the list generated by `feedparser`.

Here's my code:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import feedparser

def get_feed():
    url = "http://thefreethoughtproject.com/feed/"
    front_page = feedparser.parse(url)
    return front_page

feed = get_feed()

# make a dictionary to update with the vital information
posts = {}

for i in range(0, len(feed['entries'])):
    posts.update({
        'title': feed['entries'][i].title,
        'description': feed['entries'][i].summary,
        'url': feed['entries'][i].link,
    })

print(posts)
```

Ultimately, I'd like to have a dictionary like the following, except that it keeps going with more articles:

```
[{'Title': 'Trump Does Another Ridiculous Thing', 
  'Description': 'Witnesses looked on in awe as the Donald did this thing', 
  'Link': 'SomeNewsWebsite.com/Story12345'}, 
{...}, 
{...}]
```

Something tells me it's a simple mistake-- perhaps the syntax is off, or I'm forgetting a small yet important detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code example you provided does an `update` to the same dict over and over again. So, you only get one dict at the end of the loop. What your example data shows, is that you actually want a `list` of dictionaries:

```
# make a list to update with the vital information
posts = []

for entry in feed['entries']:
    posts.append({
        'title': entry.title,
        'description': entry.summary,
        'url': entry.link,
    })

print(posts)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the problem is that you are using a dict instead of a list. Then you are updating the same keys of the dict, so each iteration you are overriding the last content added.

I think that the following code will solve your problem:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import feedparser

def get_feed():
    url = "http://thefreethoughtproject.com/feed/"
    front_page = feedparser.parse(url)
    return front_page

feed = get_feed()

# make a dictionary to update with the vital information
posts = []  # It should be a list


for i in range(0, len(feed['entries'])):
    posts.append({
        'title': feed['entries'][i].title,
        'description': feed['entries'][i].summary,
        'url': feed['entries'][i].link,
    })

print(posts)
```

So as you can see the code above are defining the posts variable as a list. Then in the loop we are adding dicts to this list, so it will give you the data structure that you want.

I hope to help you with this solution.